# Change filename path directory

Tags: go, filepath

I need to change filename paths relative to a given folder.
I am dealing with multi-user shared buckets and it would be nice for the user not to know the complete file path.

I have an example below but it seems a bit dirty.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    secretUrl := "allusers/user/home/path/to/file"
    separator := "home/"

    newUrl := strings.Split(secretUrl, separator)

    newUserUrl := separator + newUrl[len(newUrl)-1]
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", newUserUrl)

}
```

Also, the new path needs to start from the separating point.

**Is there another way to do this more elegantly? Examples would be appreciated.**

Comment: Is the secret always going to start with `allusers/user/home/...`? Is this a URL or a file path?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What do you expect as an answer besides "yes" or "no"?

Comment: Technically, it is a key in AWS S3 bucket. So, it is a file path and sometimes considered urls too for this sake. I was more looking for something that utilized "path/filepath" package but could not find any.

Comment: May be more suited for the codereview forum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a nice platform-independent solution is to use the golang path/filepath Split function.  Does not make assumptions about what path separators look like, handles volumes, etc...

```
import (
    "path/filepath"
)

func subpath(homeDir, prevDir string) string {
    subFiles := ""
    for {
        dir, file := filepath.Split(prevDir)
        if len(subFiles) > 0 {
            subFiles = file + string(filepath.Separator) + subFiles
        } else {
            subFiles = file
        }
        if file == homeDir {
            break
        }
        if len(dir) == 0 || dir == prevDir {
            break
        }
        prevDir = dir[:len(dir) - 1]
    }
    return subFiles
}
```

Call with

```
subpath("home", "allusers/user/home/path/to/file")
```

To handle cases where "home" may appear more than once and you wish to match the first:

```
func subpath(homeDir, prevDir string) (subFiles string, found bool) {
    for {
        dir, file := filepath.Split(prevDir)
        if len(subFiles) > 0 {
            subFiles = file + string(filepath.Separator) + subFiles
        } else {
            subFiles = file
        }
        if len(dir) == 0 || dir == prevDir {
            return
        }
        prevDir = dir[:len(dir) - 1]
        if file == homeDir {
            found = true
            // look for it lower down
            lower, foundAgain := subpath(homeDir, prevDir)
            if foundAgain {
                subFiles = lower + string(filepath.Separator) + subFiles
            }
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Call with

```
path, found = subpath("home", "allusers/user/home/path/home2/home/to/file")
if found {
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", path)
} else {
    fmt.Printf("not found\n")
}
```

Comment: Great answer! please update your answer to match the first instance of homeDir i.e "allusers/user/home/path/home2/home/to/file".

Answer (score 2):

The rule of thumb is ***do not manipulate file paths as strings***. There's too many edge cases. Go has the [path](https://golang.org/pkg/path/) and [filepath](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/) libraries to manipulate paths.

But there are exceptions. Go's `path` and `filepath` libraries are limited in their functionality, like it lacks a way to split a path into an array or check if one file path is a child of another. Sometimes it's far more efficient to use string functions. You can avoid a lot of problems by first calling [`filepath.Clean`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Clean) on them to normalize them.

If the prefix is always `allusers/user/home` then you can split the paths into slices, after cleaning them, and compare them as arrays.

```
// Clean will take care of // and trailing /
secret := filepath.Clean("allusers//user/home//path/to/file")
base   := filepath.Clean("allusers/user/home/")

// Clean has made splitting on / safe.
secret_parts := strings.Split(secret, "/")
base_parts   := strings.Split(base, "/")
```

Now we have two arrays of all the pieces to compare. First, check to make sure that `base_parts` is really the prefix of `secret_parts` with [`reflect.DeepEqual`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual) on just the first few elements of `secret_parts`. The same number as in `base_parts`.

```
func sliceHasPrefix( s, prefix []string  ) bool {
    if len(s) < len(prefix) {
        return false
    }

    return reflect.DeepEqual(prefix, s[0:len(prefix)])
}
```

Then we can use [`filepath.Join`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Join) to put the remaining parts back together.

```
if sliceHasPrefix( secret_parts, base_parts ) {
    fmt.Println( filepath.Join(secret_parts[len(base_parts):]...) )
} else {
    panic("secret is not inside base")
}
```

Comment: Nice answer too about not using strings. This answer would be great if the prefix was always fixed. Unfortunately, it is not always fixed and a folder is the only thing known in advance. It is great for known file paths.

Comment: @Godfrey You can adapt it to find the index of the base directory in `secret_paths` and return a slice of `secret_paths` from that point onward. It's generally easier to work with paths as arrays.

Comment: Good idea. Either way, your answer is still insightful whether I accept it or not in the end. My strings failed miserably when the complexity increased.